# Slow query with OR in where clause

Tags: mysql

Please advise how to improve this slow query.

```
SELECT response.`reasonid`
FROM response 
    INNER JOIN ACTION ON action.actionid = response.actionid 
WHERE 
    response.respdate BETWEEN 20160305 
    AND 20160905 
    AND 
    (
        (
         response.reasonid = 'Prospect Call' 
         AND response.typeid = '0'
         AND action.typeid = '9'
        ) 
    OR 
        (
         response.typeid = '1000'  
         AND action.typeid = '1'
        )
    )
```

There are indexes on:

response.actionid / response.reasonid / response.typeid / action.typeid / response.respdate

Explain results:

```
 table   type   possible_keys                   key           key_len  ref               rows   Extra

ACTION   range  PRIMARY,idx_actiontypeid    idx_actiontypeid    5      \N               310617  Using where; Using index
response ref    idx_respdate2,idx_actionid, idx_actionid        5      ACTION.actionid    1         Using where
            idx_reasonid,idx_resptypeid
```

Comment: What data type is respdate? Is it a date, datetime, integer? And what do you mean by "slow"? 1 sec? 1 min?

Comment: respdate is a date field. slow is 6 secs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should not have individual indexes on it, but a composite or even covering indexes.  Which I am surprised nobody else commented on.  I offer the following suggestion for indexes

table     index
response  ( typeid, respdate, reasoned, actionid )
action    ( actionid, typeid )

Then I adjusted the query to use a UNION instead of an OR

```
select distinct
      r.reasonid
   from
      response r join action a
         on r.actionid = a.actionid
         AND a.typeid = 9
   where
          r.typeid = 0
      and r.respdate between 20160305 and 20160905
      and r.reasonid = 'Prospect Call'
union
select 
      r.reasonid
   from
      response r join action a
         on r.actionid = a.actionid
         AND a.typeid = 1
   where
          r.typeid = 1000
      and r.respdate between 20160305 and 20160905
```

Comment: Hi, great idea was definately faster.

Answer (score 0):

try this query added some index columns into join

```
SELECT response.`reasonid`
FROM response 
    INNER JOIN ACTION ON action.actionid = response.actionid   and response.typeid in( '1000','0') and action.typeid in('0','1')
WHERE 
    response.respdate BETWEEN 20160305 
    AND 20160905 
    AND 
    (
        (
         response.reasonid = 'Prospect Call' 
         AND response.typeid = '0'
         AND action.typeid = '9'
        ) 
    OR 
        (
         response.typeid = '1000'  
         AND action.typeid = '1'
        )
    )
```

Comment: please execute explain on this query

Comment: Thanks Manesh - but no change in query time. Have added explain above.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:
Reduce the size of the table down to only what you need to use:

```
select a.* 
from (
      SELECT response.`reasonid`
      FROM response 
      WHERE response.respdate BETWEEN 20160305 AND 20160905 
      ) a
INNER JOIN ACTION ON action.actionid = a.actionid
WHERE (
     response.reasonid = 'Prospect Call' 
     AND response.typeid = '0'
     AND action.typeid = '9'
    ) 
OR 
    (
     response.typeid = '1000'  
     AND action.typeid = '1'
    )
```

Comment: Thank you but still slow

Comment: but was it an improvement?

Comment: dont think so - due to cacheing the query runs bit faster each time anyway ;)

Comment: maybe worth trying to narrow down in even further by adding another where clause in the derived table like : WHERE response.respdate BETWEEN 20160305 AND 20160905 and response.typeID in (0,1000)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to specify the dates in your query as they are in the database:

```
SELECT response.`reasonid`
FROM response 
    INNER JOIN ACTION ON action.actionid = response.actionid 
WHERE 
    response.respdate BETWEEN "2016-03-05" 
    AND "2016-09-05" 
    AND 
    (
        (
         response.reasonid = 'Prospect Call' 
         AND response.typeid = '0'
         AND action.typeid = '9'
        ) 
    OR 
        (
         response.typeid = '1000'  
         AND action.typeid = '1'
        )
    )
```

and check if this speeds up your query.
If you write it as numeric value (20160305), the database has to do an implicit typecast on every line before comparing it, which might lead to slower performance.

Comment: Date change didnt help, but TQ